# Check if at least one of item has specific attribute term in WooCommerce order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I want to check if, at least, one of item has specific attribute term in WooCommerce order to display something in the mail order.

Attribute tax is 'pa_labels' and the term is 'tree' but something is missing... Any Idea ?

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'webroom_check_product_attr_in_order', 5 );
 
function webroom_check_product_attr_in_order( $order_id ) { 
 
if ( ! $order_id ) {
    return;
}
 
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$attr_in_order = false;

$items = $order->get_items(); 
    
foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];  
    if ( has_term( 'tree', 'pa_labels', $product_id ) ) {
        $attr_in_order = true;
        break;
    }
}
 
// Echo content only if $attr_in_order == true
   
if ( $attr_in_order ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_woocommerce_email_customer_details', 25); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// check if in the order there is at least one product with the attribute "pa_labels" => "tree"
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'webroom_check_product_attr_in_order', 5 );
function webroom_check_product_attr_in_order( $order_id ) { 
 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $attr_in_order = false;
        
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        if ( has_term( 'tree', 'pa_labels', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $attr_in_order = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Echo content only if $attr_in_order == true
    if ( $attr_in_order ) {
        custom_woocommerce_email_customer_details();
    }

}

// add content to the customer details in the email
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_woocommerce_email_customer_details', 25);
function custom_woocommerce_email_customer_details() {
    // do stuff
}
```

*The code must be added to the functions.php of the active theme.*